# Handling multiple line-ending in an asp.net

Tags: asp.net, file, parsing, web

When writing a web application which allows the upload of files, one must be concious of the fact that users of said web application may be on any operating system, including unix-like systems which use `<lf>` for line ending, mac-like systems which use `<cr>` for line endings, and windows-like systems which use `<cr><lf>` for line ending.

Assuming that I want to parse uploaded files (such as csv's) to access the data within them (for instance so as to import it into my application), is there a standard OS-agnostic method of breaking the file up into its constituent lines for further parsing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `StreamReader`.  The [ReadLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx) method handles the various types of line break:

> A line is defined as a sequence of characters followed by a line feed
>   ("\n"), a carriage return ("\r"), or a carriage return immediately
>   followed by a line feed ("\r\n"). The string that is returned does not
>   contain the terminating carriage return or line feed.